# Mule4 error handler - Enable Notifications and Log Exception

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

This is more a generic question about the usage of this feature , so please excuse the absence of code.

```
<on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="OnErrorContinue" />
```

Was reading link [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/on-error-scope-concept) but could not find any meaningful details about :

> enableNotifications="true" logException="true"

what is the significance of these attributes ?
when should they be enabled and similarly when should we NOT enable them ?

as far as I can see disabling them prevents exceptions to show up in the logs
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable notifications is to send an internal [Mule notification](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/mule-server-notifications), unrelated to logging.

Only the logException attribute activates sending the exception in the log.

Comment: thanks @aled so what is the guideline or convention to follow , should we enable or disable 'enableNotifications' ? am not clear on when we should enable or when we should not ? does it make any difference ?

Comment: Just use the default and ignore it.